# Using a chart to represent my values in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, xaml, charts

I am measuring my CPU usage and available RAM every second and also the averages for both. I have set up the code and everything is working fine. I am trying to move these values to a chart and represent the values in the chart similar to the image below.

[image: chart]

I'm not familar with charts/graphs in wpf. I have added WPF toolkit and trying to model the chart but unable to and can't find any examples/ documentations for the coding part. Didn't find much information on the xaml part either.

Would appreciate any guide. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you can find all of the resources that you'll need from the superbly named [My new home page, enhanced [Updated collection of great Silverlight/WPF Data Visualization resources!]](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/delay/archive/2009/07/19/my-new-home-page-enhanced-updated-collection-of-great-silverlight-wpf-data-visualization-resources.aspx) page from Delay's Blog on MSDN. This page has numerous links to examples on how to use the different controls including the charting controls from the WPF Toolkit.

After checking just now, I can see that some of the links no longer work, but many still do.

Comment: I did come across that page before but was confused as to whether Silver light toolkit is the same as WPF toolkit. Also as you mentioned, many links are down and fairly outdated.

Comment: That's as good an answer as you get for such a wide open question I'm afraid. Go and *try* to get the chart working and if you can't, then come back and ask a new question that [clearly describes a particular problem that you have](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Make sure that you show the relevant code too and *then* you'll get more specific help.